# Global exception catch works only while debugging the WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I implemented the following global exception `catch` in my WinForms application:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyMainForm());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: The program will be terminated. Details follow:\n\n" +
                getExceptionInfoWithDebuggerOutput(ex),
                "Global Exception",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Then down the code, an exception is raised (something as this one -- totally due to my forgetfulness):

```
public partial class MyPage : UserControl
{

    void func1()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder conStr = null;

        //... later
        conStr.DataSource = strServer;  //<<--- Where exception is raised
    }
}
```

Now, if I'm debugging my project, I see my `Global Exception` message box from the global exception handler.

But if I'm not debugging my project and run it as Ctrl+F5, or if I build a Release project, I get the following window instead of the one I coded above:

[image]

Any idea how to make my global exception handler do the processing instead?

Comment: What you have is not a global exception handler. The new form runs on a separate thread, and you have no exception handling in that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be hooking an event such as [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

These events are raised before the global error handler you're seeing in release mode. This allows you to log errors before bailing out.. in a nicer way.

There are other events that are raised also. For example, [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx). Reading the documentation will give you better insights into your specific needs.

I have to note that the error you're seeing is a `NullReferenceException`.. which would ideally be nicely handled within your code. Still, hooking these events and logging exceptions is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that catching it in the actual function would be appropriate. I'm talking about a global logging function here (last resort option so to speak.) So there's no one-catch-all solution here, right?

Comment: I have provided links to the documentation. Have a read. The events that I gave you are "one-catch-all" solutions for specific parts of your application. There is also an `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` event that is fired for every exception.. but you cannot handle these exceptions, they are merely notifications.

Comment: OK, I guess what I'm trying to say, is there a list of "what" I need to hook to, to be able to catch all possible global-scope uncaught exceptions in this application?

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.ThreadException` are the big two. If you want to log every exception, even the ones that are handled by code, then use `AppDomain.FirstChanceException`. That is "the list" as far as I am aware.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The bottom of this page has a good example of how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx